# Output a video file from ffmpeg directly to google cloud storage

Tags: google-app-engine, ffmpeg, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Background on the problem

We are trying to compress a video using FFmpeg in our server that is hosted in the Google App Engine (GAE). The input file is in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) which can be easily passed as an input to FFmpeg and the processing is done, however, I wanted to output the file directly to GCS. I have referred to the documentation here https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#http that they provided and used the correct headers and method to upload the file using a signed URL, but it doesn't seem to work. As of now, I am not even sure whether this is possible.

Current Implementation

Currently, we are first saving the output file in the GAE workspace and then uploading the file to the bucket. This flow worked fine until we faced another problem. Whenever the file is too big, the processing takes more than 10 mins which seems to be the threshold for Automatically Scaled Instances in the Flexible environment. To get around this problem we could use basic_scaling in a Standard environment but there we cannot seem to write files in the GAE workspace. I could choose to write in the `/tmp` directory but that uses RAM and we can have many files being uploaded at a time, so it's not an option.

Possible Future

Right now one solution I have seen is to use a Flexible environment with manual scaling, but this is a bad idea when it comes to scaling and cost-effectiveness. Another, which I am not so sure about would be to use Google Compute Engine but I am yet to try this.

Conclusion

The problem that arose from not being able to make a PUT request to Google Cloud Storage from FFmpeg led me to go through tens of problems surrounding GAE and its weird combination of instances and feature set.

Would really appreciate suggestions or possible solutions if I am missing anything. If only we could make the FFmpeg output the file to GCS.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to using Compute Engine. there are many options for you, depended on the programing langauge you choose.

You can upload the content to Google Storage from NodeJS, and also you can use FFMpeg library from NodeJS. Both of them without actually saving the file. Piping/Streaming directly from the input file, to Google Cloud Storage.

More info:

> FFmpeg module for Node. This library provides a set of functions and utilities to abstract commands-line usage of ffmpeg. To use this library requires that ffmpeg is already installed (including all necessary encoding libraries like libmp3lame or libx264)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg

> createWriteStream(optionsopt) → {WritableStream}
> Create a writable stream to overwrite the contents of the file in your bucket.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage

Comment: Thanks for the lead, I will look further into it. Just to be clear, if the FFMpeg library for node js supports streaming output directly to GCS, then just using the GAE should suffice, we wouldn't have to switch to Compute Engine, correct?

Comment: Not sure if you will be able to install ffmpeg module on GAE. Try it out