# How to put and access a file with FFmpeg in Google Cloude Storages?

Tags: django, heroku, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, google-cloud-storage

Hi I am a novice developer and deployed my first django project on Heroku.
I want to compress it into ffmpeg and save it to Google Cloud Storage when the user uploads a video file from uploadForm in the Django project.And by extracting the duration from the saved video using ffprobe and storing it in the duration field of object.

Save() of My forms.py code is as follows:

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        def clean_video(self):
            raw_video = self.cleaned_data.get("video")
            timestamp = int(time())
            raw_video_path = raw_video.temporary_file_path()
            print(raw_video_path)
            video_name = f"{raw_video}".split(".")[0]
            subprocess.run(f"ffmpeg -i {raw_video_path} -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 -acodec mp3 -y uploads/videoart_files/{video_name}_{timestamp}.mp4", shell=True)
            
            return f"videoart_files/{video_name}_{timestamp}.mp4"

        videoart = super().save(commit=False)
        videoart.video = clean_video(self)
        video_path = videoart.video.path
        get_duration =  subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-i', f'{video_path}', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv=%s' % ("p=0")])
        duration = int(float(get_duration.decode('utf-8').replace("\n", ""))) 
        videoart.duration = duration

        return videoart
```

After all the validation of the other fields, I put the code to process the video inside the save method to compress the video at the end. Anyway, this code is not a problem in the local server it works very well. However, the server gets a NotImplementedError ("This backend dogn't support absolute paths.") error.

Naturally, ffmpeg can receive input videos from temporary_file_path(), but it doesn't find a path to output. This absolute path is not the path of GCS.
However, ffmpeg will not recognize the url. I'm not sure how to save a file created in ffmpeg on the server to GCS and how to access it.
Don't you want to give me some advice?

Comment: can you refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68113561/15774176 Is it helpful?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav yes, but I solved the problem with gsuitl easily. but practically on my heroku server, converting video with FFmpeg is too heavy even I've changed dyno type.. so I give it up

Comment: Anyway I forgot close this question I would do soon. Thanks

Comment: can you post the answer, if it is resolved.

Comment: @DivyaniYadav https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp I installed gsutil and I used a command cp *.txt gs://my-bucket on my django app. this command would put the file on storage. but finally, I don't use any more this. with this way, I had to save directly url of file on DB and I could not use django-cleanup